# Sign In problem when executing an Apex application

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I was working on an apex application some minutes ago and I can no longer enter, it just shows this:

[Image 1: There is nothing in this page! just a Sing In title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVgmH.png)

There is this title "Sign In" but I don't know what happens, I haven't seen that before.

I tried executing another application and I get something pretty similar, but in this case, it gave me a log in form, I entered but nothing happened, just an error:

[Image 2: Idk if this error is due to the application, but the point is that I can't enter to any application now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHzsY.png)

Please help, this is an important project :(. Thank you.

Comment: Run you page in debug mode (change the NO in the URL to a YES), then look for details on the complaint it has. Is a table missing? Have the conditions to regions on the login page failed/returned false? Why is an important project on apex.oracle.com?

Comment: What worries me is **is_internal_error: TRUE**. As if someone dropped a table they shouldn't have (the one that belongs to Apex). Or, if it is a custom-made authentication, you're probably fetching username/password data from that table. Do you have access to it? Is it owned by you? Are certain privileges missing (SELECT would do, I presume)?